# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.net: intellisense with .aspx files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

This may be a dumb question but haven't been able to find an answer just by Googling. Is it possible to get intellisense to work with .aspx files? VS is just showing all the code in plain white text. Here's a snippet of the my aspx file looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Common" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>


<%   
   bool DEBUG_MODE = false;
   string logFileName = "LOG_FILE";

   XmlNode root, rootchild, outerXnode, innerXnode;
   string SQL, BRDCST_NUM;    
   XmlDocument oXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
   Stopwatch stopwatch = null;
   TimeSpan elapsed;
   DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

   root = oXMLDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "broadcasts", "");
   oXMLDoc.AppendChild(root);

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(BRDCST_NUM))
   {
       XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"firstLoad2", "");
       root.AppendChild(firstLoad2);
   }
 %>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Does it work when you use the codebehind? If you go to the file properties, is it set to "Content" ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using codebehind. How do I go about using that? Yes the build action is set to "Content".

Comment: What is your project type?

Comment: it's a WCF project.

Comment: You should be able to right click on the project, choose "Add" --> "New Item... ", then from the list, pick "Web Form". This will add an aspx to your project, and if you expand the glyph next to the new file it will show as aspx.cs and aspx.designer.cs. The aspx.cs is the code behind file and where you should try to put c#/vb.net code so its easier to work with compared to interspersed in the aspx markup.